# How to assign color obtained by CSS gradient generator

Tags: jquery, css

I am using CSS gradient generator color in a button in my website.When user hovers mouse over the button,color changes to red and then after mouse is not over button,I want color generated by CSS gradient generator.

The code provided by CSS gradient generator is

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left top,
right bottom,
color-stop(0, #423F42),
color-stop(1, #E3E3E3)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, #423F42 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right bottom, #423F42 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, #423F42 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right bottom, #423F42 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #423F42 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
```

The Jquery code used for changing color when mouse hovers over button is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function mOver(obj) {
obj.style.background = "CSS gradient color";
}

function mOut(obj) {
 obj.style.background = "#586161";
}
});
```

How do I achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to not use Javascript for something that should be handled with CSS.

```css
button {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right bottom,
    color-stop(0, #423F42),
    color-stop(1, #E3E3E3)
    );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, #423F42 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right bottom, #423F42 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, #423F42 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right bottom, #423F42 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #423F42 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
}

button:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```